# How to increment some data with LoopBack 3 without harming consistency?

Tags: javascript, mysql, loopbackjs, consistency

I am building an API where some  fields can be incremented.

After noticing data inconsistency in my MySQL database, I realized that the first version of my code was buggy:

```
Answer.incrementVotesCount = async (id) => {
    // get a copy of the data
    let answer = await getAnswer(id);

    // update the copy of the data locally
    answer.votesCount++;
    // replace the persisted data with the updated copy of the original data
    await Answer.updateAll({id}, answer);
};
```

Getting some data, updating it locally and persisting the modification can cause consistency problems when the route is used several times in a short period of time.

Such a situation would look something like this:

- Caller A gets data. The persisted `votesCount` equals 14.
- Caller B gets data. The persisted `votesCount` equals 14.
- Caller A updates data. The persisted `votesCount` becomes 14 + 1.
- At this point, the persisted `votesCount` equals 15, but Caller B's copy of it still equals 14.
- Caller B updates data. The persisted `votesCount` becomes 14 + 1, whereas it should become 15 + 1.

2 increments have been performed, but the second one "crushed" the first one, since it increments an obsolete data.

I thought about using LoopBack3's [native SQL](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Executing-native-SQL.html) functionality, but it seems like it is not fully reliable so I am unsure whether it's a good idea to use it (even though a query as simple as `SET a = a + 1` should probably work correctly).

I also thought about using MySQL's triggers to perform some ACID compliant incrementing but I am unsure I can find a clean way to do this.

How do I increment some data without making it inconsistent?

Answer (score 0):

I would take away the `votesCount` field to a separate `hasOne` relation, then I would make the `Answer` model strict='filter', so it would prevent saving data that does not really belong to the model. And when vote-up action would be taken I would increase the `voteCount` in that separate model, independently of the original `Answer`.

If you don't want to do it like this, you can try to check the original value in the `before save` hook, so you could get the latest value from the db and compare `votesCount` value from the database with the value in the model and update it accordingly.